# How to make this vba code retrieve 2 tables instead of 1 from the internet

Tags: vba, excel

I am a geologist working in the oil and gas business. I am also responsible for all of our technology. Over the past few weeks I have been designing a macro that interfaces with the Louisiana Department of Natural Resources website in order o create a program that automatically compiles production information. This website has been a huge help and the advice given by the users has been invaluable. I am once again stuck though, and in need of some help.

Before I get into what I need, I just want to credit the users @Jeeped and @mrbungle for creating this code. It works just like I asked and has been a enormous success.

The way the code works is that the code takes a serial number of a oil well (in column A) and then goes out to the Louisiana DNR website and uses this serial number to download the production report into a new worksheet. This new worksheet is named based on the value in Column C of the first worksheet.

Currently, the code is written to retrieve the entire report and then to cut all the information out except for one table that I am interested in.

I would like to preserve 2 tables now instead of 1. I cant figure out how to do it. I have attempted to add a frow2 and lrow2 variable (that equate to the second table I want preserved) however due to the cut function, only the lower table will be preserved since the cut function cuts all data above a certain point. I think the answer lies somewhere in how to word the cut function. I cant figure out how to do it though.

The way the cut function works presently is that it cuts all data above and below certain table names on the downloaded sheet

The tables I would like to preserve are (in order) the "Wells" and the "Perforations" table

Here is a serial number to a well in case you want to test out the program: 57711

The code is below

```
Option Explicit

Public Const csURL As String =       "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=×WSN×"
Sub Gather_Perforations_Data()
Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, w As Long, wsn As String, wb As Workbook, frow As String, lrow As String

On Error Resume Next
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Exception occured: " & Err.Decscription

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False



With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WSNs")
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For rw = 2 To lr
        .Cells(rw, 2) = 0
        For w = 1 To .Parent.Sheets.Count
            If .Parent.Sheets(w).Name = CStr(.Cells(rw, 1).Value) Then
                .Parent.Sheets(w).Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next w
        wsn = Replace(csURL, "×WSN×", .Cells(rw, 1).Value)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wsn, ReadOnly:=True, addtomru:=False)

        frow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Perforations", Range("A:A"), 0)
        lrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Well Tests", Range("A:A"), 0)
        lrow = lrow - 1
        frow = "A" & frow
        lrow = "F" & lrow
        Range(frow, lrow).Cut Range("Q1")
        Columns("A:P").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A3").Font.Size = 12
        wb.Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count)
        .Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count).Name = .Cells(rw, 3).Value
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
        .Cells(rw, 2) = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Parent.Save
    Next rw
    .Activate
End With
```

Fìn:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Please let me know if I can explain anything better.

Comment: can you give an example value for xWSNx so we can have a look at the page in question? - nevermind, think you gave one already

Comment: ya that serial number is the example of a xWSNx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Const csURL As String = "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=×WSN×"
Sub Gather_Perforations_Data_save_api_row()
Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, w As Long, wsn As String, wb As Workbook, frow As String, lrow As String, lrow2 As String, frow2 As String

On Error Resume Next
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Exception occured: " & Err.Decscription

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False



With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WSNs")
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For rw = 2 To lr
        .Cells(rw, 2) = 0
        For w = 1 To .Parent.Sheets.Count
            If .Parent.Sheets(w).Name = CStr(.Cells(rw, 1).Value) Then
                .Parent.Sheets(w).Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next w
        wsn = Replace(csURL, "×WSN×", .Cells(rw, 1).Value)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wsn, ReadOnly:=True, addtomru:=False)


        frow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Wells", Range("A:A"), 0)
        lrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Well Tests", Range("A:A"), 0)
        lrow = lrow - 1
        frow = "A" & frow
        lrow = "O" & lrow
        Range(frow, lrow).Cut Range("Q1")
        Columns("A:P").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


        frow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Well Surface Coordinates", Range("A:A"), 0)
        lrow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Perforations", Range("A:A"), 0)
        lrow2 = lrow2 - 1
        frow2 = "A" & frow2
        lrow2 = "P" & lrow2
        Range(frow2, lrow2).Delete




        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A3").Font.Size = 12
        wb.Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count)
        .Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count).Name = .Cells(rw, 3).Value
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
        .Cells(rw, 2) = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Parent.Save
    Next rw
    .Activate
End With
Fìn:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks everyone for looking at it.

Comment: Mark this as an answer.

Comment: I cant for 2 days the system is tellin gme